# Can't import materialize modules with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, import, materialize

Trying to use materializecss with webpack. What I want to do is to import only the required Modules not all of the js. Loading the complete js is working as expected. But if I only want to use a modal, I cant find out how to do it. 
I tried

```
    import 'materialize-css/js/modal.js';
```

result: Uncaught ReferenceError: cash is not defined
Then I tried:

```
   import 'materialize-css/js/cash.js';
   import 'materialize-css/js/component.js';
   import 'materialize-css/js/global.js';
   import 'materialize-css/js/anime.min.js';
   import 'materialize-css/js/modal.js';
```

Result: modal.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: Component is not defined.

I wonder if there is a way to use materializecss in a modular way with webpack?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: You would probably use something along the lines of `import { Modal } from 'materialize-css';`

Comment: @ChrisG: Thanks a bunch, this realy worked, but I have not a single byte saved in filesize. And I am not so sure how it worked. Anyway, thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's very possible that webpack doesn't import the entire module but just the stuff that's used in your code. That would explain why it made no difference in file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
import {
    Modal,
    Dropdown
} from 'materialize-css';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var modals = M.Modal.init(document.querySelectorAll('.modal'), {});
    var dropdowns = M.Dropdown.init(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger'), {});
});
```

Import the components you want to use and initialize them individually.